# Output encoding change with new LaTeX 2020/02/02

Tags: pdftex

The following test file outputs OT1 encoded fonts for French when compiled with pdfLaTeX <2020-02-02> and T1 encoded fonts (as expected)  when compiled with pdfLaTeX <2019-10-01> Patch Level 3.  Is this change intended?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
\section{По Русски} 
Проба Пера

\selectlanguage{french} 
\section{Du français} 
\og Été à l'hôtel \fg. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm. babel tests if t1enc.def is loaded to decide if it should change \latinencoding. But the t1-definitions are loaded in the format and fontenc  doesn't reload t1enc.def again and so the test fails. I'm not sure what babel should do here, but you should make a bug report. A work around is to define \latinencoding directly with `\AtBeginDocument{\def\latinencoding{T1}}`.

Comment: I think I will add an issue to the babel tracker myself.

Comment: Well imho the setting of \latinencoding in babel was a bit sketchy anyway. E.g. it wouldn't have worked properly with LY1 encoding. There is some guess work involved which now breaks.  This should be improved.